# How to set custom time out for remember me cookie in grails spring security?

Tags: grails, spring-security, remember-me

I have `tokenValiditySeconds` set in the `Config.groovy` as

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.tokenValiditySeconds=31*24*60*60
```

However I want to set a different validity for all requests that comes from, say a sub-domain. I can identify domain info from the `request` object, but I am not able to override the `tokenValiditySeconds` from the `CustomRememberMeService` class.

> By default the tokens will be valid for 14 days from the last
>   successful authentication attempt. This can be changed using
>   AbstractRememberMeServices.setTokenValiditySeconds(int). If this value
>   is less than zero, the expiryTime will remain at 14 days, but the
>   negative value will be used for the maxAge property of the cookie,
>   meaning that it will not be stored when the browser is closed.

As per the documentation, I should be able to change the validity by using `setTokenValiditySeconds(int)` method but it does not have any effect.

So how to override the value set in the config file?

Thanks.

Edit:

```
class CustomRememberMeService extends TokenBasedRememberMeServices {
    def springSecurityService;

    public final LoggedInUserDetails customAutoLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        def cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (!cookies) return null;
        String rememberMeCookie = extractRememberMeCookie(request);
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            Cookie c = cookies[i];
            if(c.getName().equals('remember_me') && rememberMeCookie == null) {
                rememberMeCookie = c.getValue();
            }
        }
        if (rememberMeCookie == null) return null
        logger.debug("rememberMeCookie is : ${rememberMeCookie}");

        if (rememberMeCookie.length() == 0) {
            cancelCookie(request, response);
            return null;
        }

        String[] cookieTokens = decodeCookie(rememberMeCookie);
        String username = cookieTokens[0];

        def loginContext = request.getParameter('loginContext')
        loginContext = (loginContext == null) ? "mainWeb" : loginContext

        setTokenValiditySeconds(60) // not working

        LoggedInUserDetails user = getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername("${username}#${request.getServerName().trim()}#${loginContext}")

        springSecurityService.reauthenticate("${username}#${request.getServerName().trim()}#${loginContext}")
    }
}
```

The resource.groovy file looks like:

```
//..
customRememberMeService(com.rwi.springsecurity.services.CustomRememberMeService) {
    userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
    springSecurityService = ref('springSecurityService')
    key = "${grailsApplication.config.grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.key}"
}
customRememberMeServicesFilter(CustomRememberMeServicesFilter){
    authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
    rememberMeServices = ref('rememberMeServices')
    customRememberMeService = ref('customRememberMeService')
}
//..
```

CustomRemeberMEService.groovy

```
// ..
class CustomRememberMeServicesFilter extends RememberMeAuthenticationFilter {
    def customRememberMeService;
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            LoggedInUserDetails rememberMeAuth = customRememberMeService.customAutoLogin(request, response);
        }   
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your CustomRememberMyService and how you're registering it (e.g your conf/spring/resources.groovy)

Comment: user2264997: ok. I will update it. Currently I am away from the code.

Comment: Update the question to include the current code.

Comment: The `setTokenValiditySeconds` is a configuration option, calling it in code after the cookie has been created is basically not going to do anything (at least not for the cookie that is already there).

Comment: M. Deinum: So how can I have a customize the cookie setting part? I think the remember me cookie is set from the `AbstractRememberMeService.groovy` class (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/AbstractRememberMeServices.java#L342-L361).

Comment: I had override the `setCookie()` method in my `CustomRememberMeService` class, but it still sets the `maxAge` to the value specified in the `Config.groovy` even if I pass in `maxAge` as `60`.

Answer (score 1):

Override the method `calculateLoginLifetime`, by default this will return the value as set in the configuration (it calls `getTokenValiditySeconds()`. By overriding this you can determine (based on the request) if the normal timeout should be passed or a custom one.

```
protected int calculateLoginLifetime(HttpServletRequest request, Authentication authentication) {
    if (request.getRemoteAddr().startsWith("subdomain") {
        return 15; // Or whatever you want, you could also make it configurable.
    }
    return getTokenValiditySeconds();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will look into, but it will take quite a bit of time. Will respond after that.

Comment: This is not working. It still uses the value specified in the config file.

Comment: Make sure you are **only** overriding the `calculateLoginLifetime` and that your instance is also the actual instance getting used.